# Cocoa Touch: What is the purpose of the View Controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm confused about the purpose and role of [**ViewControllers**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) in iPhone (cocoa touch) programming.  I understand the general concept of MVC (Model View Controller), but Apple seems to have assigned [specific meaning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) to the ViewController as a controller that manages views, and interacts between views and the data layer.

Actually, I understand what a ViewController *does*: it "manages views".  What I'm missing is the "why".  I can manage views just fine, by for example, creating a main view in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, without using a ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Create the main view
    //
    const float width = self.window.frame.size.width;
    const float height = self.window.frame.size.height;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: rect];
    [self.window addSubview: mainvView];

    // etc. etc...
}
```

So what is the purpose of the ViewController?  How does it make the programmer's job easier?

Comment: If you understand the concept of MVC then you respect the desire to separate concerns in the code. Views are for display, not for 'business' / control logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually your application delegate is a view controller (I don't mean app delegates are in general, I mean YOUR app delegate).
The fact that it is not inheriting from UIViewController is irrelevant from a conceptual point of view. Its controlling views therefore its a view controller, its just not a descendant of UIViewController thats all.

Now imagine you have 5, 10, 100, 500 views to display and manage. What are you going to do? - add hundreds or thousands of additional lines of code in your application delegate till you have a huge mess of code? In addition to controlling the views you could also add all your other model code there too if you wanted.

Well you can if you want to, nobody and nothing is stopping you.

But if you wanted to make your code neater and tidier and easier to manage, implement and maintain, decoupled, and if in addition you wanted to take advantage of much functionality that the OS provides to help manage all those views then you'd start to use UIViewControllers to make managing those 500 views easier and saner and make your life simple. Wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

They provide a standard, predictable mechanism with a well-defined lifecycle. Technically, they're not needed. But they do help in the sense that they're Apple's recommended way of handling the Controller part of MVC and they have a lot of tooling around it (Cocoa Touch, IB, etc) to help use it.

Answer (score 0):

*View Controller* not only manages its own *View*, but also nicely integrates with other UIKit classes. It has a *Title*, *Navigation Item* and *Toolbar items*, that are used without the *View* even being created (which is an expensive operation).

*View Controller* also allows you easily use *Interface Builder* to create the *View* while still be able implement some logic before and after the NIB is loaded.